# issue with header image - object-fit: contain

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a responsive image header, but it does not seem to be working correctly, should I be putting the class on the image or a div container?

I obviously need it at the top of the page at multiple heights with different images across the devices,

This is the image tag I am using, which should serve the different images?

```
<img src="img/images-header.jpg"
     srcset="img/images-header@2x.jpg 2x,
             img/images-header@3x.jpg 3x"
     class="Images-Header">
```

These are the css rules across devices:

```
.Images-Header {
  width: 320px;
  height: 456px;
  margin: 60px 0 0;
  padding: 105px 29px;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.Images-Header {
  width: 768px;
  height: 296px;
  margin: 60px 0 0;
  padding: 25px 392px 25px 97px;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.Images-Header {
  width: 992px;
  height: 492px;
  margin: 85px 0 0;
  padding: 72px 511px 72px 111px;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.Images-Header {
  width: 1920px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 85px 0 0;
  padding: 76px 975px 76px 500px;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong for it not to display properly?

The padding is for some text that overlays the image

Many thanks,

Ed

Comment: you are repeating the rule with different values, so it only apply the last rule

Comment: sorry I took the rules outside of the media queries for this example